# Align Center inbetween 2 floated

Tags: html, css, alignment

http://www.capitalregionceremonies.net/

On the bottom of the front-page, i'd like to put the weddingwire award block in the center of the 2 other badges but I can't seem to find a way. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Add custom widget. its simple in wordpress.

Comment: I see only two badges: one for WeddingWire, and one for TheKnot...?

Comment: You will need to restructure your HTML. Why do you have so many `<script>` tags within `<p>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup seems a bit odd, I'm not sure if you are entering code in your CMS or the source files. Regardless, you should be able to attain the layout you want with this sort of code structure below.

If you are not familiar with CSS, and have no idea how to add the first block of code, you can edit it at Appearance > Customize > CSS in WordPress ([reference](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/how-to-find-your-themes-css/)), or you could just add them inline to your elements instead (not recommended but may be easier depending on your abilities).

```css
.column-left {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
.column-right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 33%;
}
.column-center {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-left">
  <a href="http://www.theknot.com/marketplace/reverend-ronald-hunt-capital-region-ceremonies-rotterdam-ny-550208?utm_source=vendor_website&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_term=6d82f360-5321-42a9-bd35-a16c012a8cd4&amp;utm_campaign=vendor_badge_assets">
    <img src="http://www.capitalregionceremonies.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ASI_2-e1452633825381.png" alt="As Seen in The Knot Magazine" width="75" height="150" border="0">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="column-center">
  <div class="ww-bca-2014 ww-reset">
    <a class="ww-bca-top" title="Weddings, Wedding Venues" href="http://www.weddingwire.com">
      <br>
    </a>
    <a class="ww-bca-top" href="http://www.weddingwire.com">
      <img class="alignnone" src="//www.weddingwire.com/assets/badges/BCA-2014/BCA_2014-badge-top.png" alt="Weddings, Wedding Venues" width="124" height="33">
    </a>
    <a class="ww-bca-bottom" title="Celebrant Ronald Hunt Reviews, Best Wedding Officiants in Albany, Saratoga Springs, Adirondacks - 2014 Couples' Choice Award Winner" href="http://www.weddingwire.com/reviews/celebrant-ronald-hunt-rotterdam/402496f5dd9397b7.html">
      <br>
    </a>
    <a class="ww-bca-bottom" href="http://www.weddingwire.com/reviews/celebrant-ronald-hunt-rotterdam/402496f5dd9397b7.html">
      <img class="alignnone" src="//www.weddingwire.com/assets/badges/BCA-2014/BCA_2014-badge-bottom.png" alt="Celebrant Ronald Hunt Reviews, Best Wedding Officiants in Albany, Saratoga Springs, Adirondacks - 2014 Couples' Choice Award Winner" width="124" height="92">
    </a>
    <p></p>
    <div class="ww-clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column-right">
  <a href="http://www.celebrantinstitute.org" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://www.celebrantinstitute.org/logo/life-cycleLogo-5-2010.gif" alt="Celebrant USA Foundation and Institute" border="0">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it in all browsers but this should do it. Just wrap the elements you are trying to line up in a div

```
<div>

  <div style="float: left">
    <a style="" href="http://www.theknot.com/marketplace/reverend-ronald-hunt-capital-region-ceremonies-rotterdam-ny-550208?utm_source=vendor_website&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_term=6d82f360-5321-42a9-bd35-a16c012a8cd4&amp;utm_campaign=vendor_badge_assets"><img src="http://www.capitalregionceremonies.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ASI_2-e1452633825381.png" alt="As Seen in The Knot Magazine" width="75" height="150" border="0"></a>
  </div>

    <div style="float: right;">
    <a href="http://www.celebrantinstitute.org" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.celebrantinstitute.org/logo/life-cycleLogo-5-2010.gif" alt="Celebrant USA Foundation and Institute" border="0"></a>
</div>

<div class="ww-bca-2014" style="">
  <a class="ww-bca-top" title="Weddings, Wedding Venues" href="http://www.weddingwire.com"><br>
</a>
  <a class="ww-bca-top" href="http://www.weddingwire.com"><img class="alignnone" src="//www.weddingwire.com/assets/badges/BCA-2014/BCA_2014-badge-top.png" alt="Weddings, Wedding Venues" width="124" height="33"></a><a class="ww-bca-bottom" title="Celebrant Ronald Hunt Reviews, Best Wedding Officiants in Albany, Saratoga Springs, Adirondacks - 2014 Couples' Choice Award Winner" href="http://www.weddingwire.com/reviews/celebrant-ronald-hunt-rotterdam/402496f5dd9397b7.html"><br>
</a>

  <a class="ww-bca-bottom" href="http://www.weddingwire.com/reviews/celebrant-ronald-hunt-rotterdam/402496f5dd9397b7.html"><img class="alignnone" src="//www.weddingwire.com/assets/badges/BCA-2014/BCA_2014-badge-bottom.png" alt="Celebrant Ronald Hunt Reviews, Best Wedding Officiants in Albany, Saratoga Springs, Adirondacks - 2014 Couples' Choice Award Winner" width="124" height="92"></a>
  <p></p>
</div>

</div>
```